# Centering multiple side-by-side divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make multiple divs, specifically five and center them all. I have used the `display:inline-block` to get them to be side by side but then when I use `margin: 0 auto`, the `display:inline-block` seems to get negated and then it's a vertical strip going down the page.

Below is my code:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
}
#orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="orange"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

I tried looking at the other relevant posts on SO but they don't do it with as many divs or they use static positioning which I don't want to use.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens cause the width of the container is 50px. One quick solution is to set `width` of container to 100%:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
}
#orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="orange"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

You can align to center using `text-align` center to container:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
}
#orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="orange"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

To achieve both and vertical and horizontal align you can use `position: absolute` to the container `top: 50%` `left: 50%` and `margin-top: -150px; /* Half the height */` `margin-left: -135px; /* Half the width */`:

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 0;
    display:inline-block;
}
#red {
    background-color: red;
}
#orange {
    background-color: orange;
}
#yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#green {
    background-color: green;
}
#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.container {
    width: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top: -150px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -135px; /* Half the width */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="orange"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gah, I was too slow :)

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I wanted. I just had a quick question. Suppose I change the width to `100px`, since I doubled my width, I also changed `.container` `width: 540px` i.e. doubled that and then changed the `margin-left` to `-270px`. Does the principle of doubling or multiplying it by a certain ratio apply when I change the width to some arbitary?

Comment: `margin-left` must always be equal to -width(of the element) / 2.

Comment: @AlexChar Thanks for the reminder, totally forgot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set text-align: center on .container. Updated you code:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > div{
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 0;
    display:inline-block;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jermund/wzdLrs0m/